# Infra Red Send Hex Code

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using an arduino nano with the standard arduino IR remote library. For now I am using the Irrecord sketch. However, I want to have some pre - programed codes for remotes I don't have. I found this [site](http://www.remotecentral.com/cgi-bin/codes/) which apparently has the hex of an endless number of remotes. When I use the regular IR decode, the hex of any remote I use, is only a couple of characters.  However at this site the typical amount is at least 100.

This is the hex for a Toshiba model's sleep command:

0000 006c 0022 0002 0157 00ab 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0040 0016 0016 0016 0040 0016 0040 0016 0040 0016 0040 0016 0040 0016 0040 0016 0016 0016 0040 0016 0040 0016 0016 0016 0040 0016 0016 0016 0040 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0040 0016 0016 0016 0040 0016 0016 0016 0040 0016 0040 0016 0040 0016 05f0 0157 0055 0016 0e52

So, finally after all that if you are still with me my question is, how would I send that command with the IRRemote library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be pronto hex format for codes. A quick google showed this explanation: http://www.remotecentral.com/features/irdisp2.htm and this sample code: https://gist.github.com/probonopd/5793692

Comment: Is there some converter I could use to convert it into regular or do I have to deal with it directly.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by regular. The pronto codes are just durations of on and off. So you don't need to know which code is used exactly. The code that I linked has an example sketch (https://gist.github.com/probonopd/5793692#file-sendprontohex-ino) which takes codes from serial and sends them. This could be easily adjusted to send the codes from an array. The function that does the sending is `ir_start` in `loop`

Comment: I mean, is there a way I could integrate that into the example in the irremote library?

Comment: It can be made into its own lib or probably added to that library, but this is beyond the scope of this answer. If you make it work as a regular sketch then can read about creating libraries and make one. That would be the simplest way instead of integrating with the existing one.